# Best practice for sending segments to the Model?

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter

I was wondering what are the best practice before sending segment to the Model.

For example:

Get the segment1 from 
base_url/controller/query_detail/segment1

on my controller

```
public function query_detail($segment1)
{
//what are the best practice before I send the segment1 to the Model?
   $this->load->model('model');
   $this->model->query($segment1);   
   ......  
}
```

I hope I explain well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: sorry, doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to sending data to a model to run an insert or an update with that data, then best practices are to validate input at the time the user submits it. Then since codeigniter does cleansing of data when used as bound data, then you could run an insert as such;

```
# This would be in your model...not your controller
function store_data($post_data) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO some_table set (fld1, fld2, fld3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
  $binds = array($post_data['fld1'], $post_data['fld2'], $post_data['fld3']);
  $this-db->query($sql, $binds);
}
```

Or if all your incoming form's input tag names match your database column names, then you could simply do this;

```
# This would be in your model...not your controller
function store_data($post_data) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO some_table set (fld1, fld2, fld3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
  $binds = array($post_data);
  $this-db->query($sql, $binds);
}
```

Or this;

```
# This would be in your model...not your controller
# Using ActiveRecord
function store_data($post_data) {
  $this->db->insert('some_table', $post_data);
}
```

Comment: Just exactly what I need. Thank you Skittles.